# img is not displayed in JSP/TomCat

Tags: java, image, jsp, tomcat

I've seen a lot of thread about the same problem. However all the solutions are not working for me. The problem is simple: my image is not displayed on my page, it is replace by the alt text.

**Path of my image:** *WebContent/LIB/image/my-image.png*
- This is not in the WEB-INF folder (good practice).
- I tried with another image (.jpg), but failed.
I saw a lot of people explain that the real problem was the path. I tried all these path but any one was working:

```
<img src='<c:url value="/LIB/image/my-image.png"/>' alt="KO"/>
// http://localhost:8080/3JVA-Project-SupTrip/WebContent/LIB/image/%3Cc:url%20value=%22/LIB/image/my-image.png%22/%3E

<img src="LIB/image/my-image.png" alt="KO"/>
// http://localhost:8080/3JVA-Project-SupTrip/WebContent/LIB/image/LIB/image/my-image.png

<img src="/LIB/image/my-image.png" alt="KO"/>
// http://localhost:8080/LIB/image/my-image.png

<img src="../LIB/image/my-image.png" alt="KO"/>
// http://localhost:8080/3JVA-Project-SupTrip/WebContent/LIB/LIB/image/my-image.png

<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/LIB/image/my-image.png" alt="KO"/>
// http://localhost:8080/3JVA-Project-SupTrip/LIB/image/my-image.png

<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/WebContent/LIB/image/my-image.png" alt="KO"/>
// http://localhost:8080/3JVA-Project-SupTrip/WebContent/LIB/image/my-image.png
```

**This is the logical URI for my image:** *http://localhost:8080/3JVA-Project-SupTrip/WebContent/LIB/image/my-image.png*

I really need your help, thank you buddies.

**EDIT:** Add some comments with the URI (last one sounds perfect but not working)

For example, this include works:

```
<!-- Main CSS -->
<style type="text/css">
    <%@ include file="../LIB/css/main.css" %>
</style>
```

**Structure:**
-3JVA-Project-SupTrip
--build
--src
--WebContent
---LIB
----image
-----my-image.png
---META-INF
---WEB-INF

Comment: Can you using a web inspector or something similar, add as comment next to each `<img src=` the resulting `src` (for the computed ones)?

Comment: "last one sounds perfect but not working" so the url is probably not what you expect it to be. You should add your war structure to your question.

Comment: I added the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use this path,

```
<img src="/LIB/image/my-image.png" alt="KO"/>
```

It should be work because in my case it works fine.

Also, if you feel free then change name from 'LIB' to 'assets'.

**EDITED :**

```
<input type="image" src="LIB/image/ttt.jpg"/>
```

**EDITED REPEAT**

```
<img src="LIB/image/bg.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

Kindly confirm it, it works in all cases.

Comment: I used this path but it is not working. So if the path is good, what is the problem ? Must I add an extra .jsp stuff ? Any idea ?

Comment: wait i help you. follow what i say, first of all find path of tomcat where you app deployed, probably somethig like, C://tomcat-XX/..../webapps/appNAme/..... my concern is check whether our image directory is available into tomcat dir where app deploy. check it first, till now i give you other hint.

Comment: use this to figure out where is your app running,  String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") ; it will give you full path then after go to manually there and check full path in order to reach image then just add that extra path into here like getRealPath("/LIB/images...")

Comment: I hope above my hint works perfectly. please try it as soon as possible to fix it.

Comment: I hope above my hint works perfectly. please try it as soon as possible to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I was away. No I didn't solve it yet, to be honest I don't really understand what can I do. The full path is: G:\workspace-eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\3JVA-Project-SupTrip\

Comment: @C0ZEN let's go step by step, first use this <%= request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") %> which will print tomcat dir path where your app runs. get that path first then reply me

Comment: G:\workspace-eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\3JVA-Project-SupTrip\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96467/discussion-between-vishal-gajera-and-c0zen).

Comment: Great, now go to that path manually(browse window) and see are you able to see LIB dir, or some otherDir/LIB ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96483/discussion-between-vishal-gajera-and-c0zen).

Comment: Kindly refer 'EDITED REPEAT' which will work for you too. cheers!!

Comment: I have been tested with 2-Editer ( Eclipse/Netbean ) last one 'EDITED REPEAT' works perfect into all cases.